# invalid get index transform on base null instance

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am trying to build something that checks the game mode variables to choose which character to load but in the line that sets the position I get invalid get index transform on base null instance I know why I am getting this error I just don't know how to fix it. and here is the code:

```
extends Spatial

var player

func _ready():
    if Glabal.shoot_game_mode == true:
        player = preload("res://Playerbutwithagun.tscn").instance(PackedScene.GEN_EDIT_STATE_MAIN)
        player.transform.origin = $Position3D.transform.origin
    elif Glabal.classic_game_mode == true:
        player = preload("res://Player.tscn").instance()
        player.transform.origin = $Position3D.transform.origin
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really give you a solution, but I don't think you know why you are getting that error. I do believe you do have an hypothesis… You should test your hypothesis.

What we know is that you have an error similar to this:

> "invalid get index transform on base null instance"

Which tells you you are accessing `transform` on something something on a null instance. Which is your hypothesis? What do you think is null? Do you think `$Position` is null? Try `print($Position)`. It isn't? Then perhaps `player` is null? Try `print(player)`.

I don't have your code. So I can't do that. Instead of testing, I must analyze the possibilities.

---

By the way, it is not something typed as `null`, or it would say:

> Invalid get index 'transform' (on base: 'Nil').

---

If `$Position3D.transform` causes this error:

> "invalid get index transform on base null instance"

It would mean that `$Position3D` is a null instance. But how could that be?

The expression `$Position3D` is equivalent to `get_node("Position3D")`. It is looking for a child `Node` with `name` set to "Position3D". However, is there weren't such a node you would get this error on runtime:

> get_node: (Node not found: "Position3D" (relative to "/root/scene/node/path").)

Therefore the node is there. Also, you are not getting a reference to a deleted object because you would have:

> Invalid get index 'transform' (on base: 'previously freed instance').

Accompanied with errors about attempting to access a deleted object. Besides, you would only have such reference if it was freed after you got it. But there is no room for that to happen in your code. *Well, I don't know if you are using threading, but I'm assuming you don't.*

So, I believe `$Position3D.transform` works.

---

The other option is that `player.transform` causes this error:

> "invalid get index transform on base null instance"

Which would imply that `instance` returned null. But how could that be?

Clearly you are able to `preload` the scenes. If it could not load the resource you would have an error about that (and `preload` is checked statically). And the resource it loads must be a `PackedScene` since you are not getting an around like this:

> Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'instance' in base 'Resource'.

*Also the `tscn` extension is for `PackedScene`s.*

This means that this line does not have a reason to fail:

```
player = preload("res://Player.tscn").instance()
```

This other line however…

```
player = preload("res://Playerbutwithagun.tscn").instance(PackedScene.GEN_EDIT_STATE_MAIN)
```

The [documentation about `GEN_EDIT_STATE_MAIN`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_packedscene.html#class-packedscene-constant-gen-edit-state-main) says that it is only available on editor builds. Thus, it will fail on the exported game.

Can `instance` return null? Yes it can, see the [source code of `instance`](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.x/scene/resources/packed_scene.cpp#L1600).

But will it? Well, now I have an hypothesis that I can test: That instancing with `PackedScene.GEN_EDIT_STATE_MAIN` will work on the editor, but not on the exported game. So I did!

I can confirm it works on the editor. But on the exported game (with debug) I got this:

> ERROR: Edit state is only for editors, does not work without tools compiled.
> at: (scene/resources/packed_scene.cpp:1642)
> SCRIPT ERROR: Invalid get index 'transform' (on base: 'null instance').
> at: _ready (res://template/scenes/ui/ui.gdc:11)

---

Now, I don't know why you are trying to use `GEN_EDIT_STATE_MAIN`. And that is why I cannot really give a solution.

Evidently, if this is the problem, you should try to make it work without `GEN_EDIT_STATE_MAIN`. So, I would say remove it, and see if it breaks. And if it does, look for a workaround for the specific way it breaks. *For which, I have no information to tell you a solution.*

---

*I may of course, be wrong. I could have missed something… It could be a known unknown (for example, it could be a bug fixed between Godot versions, but I don't know which version you are using)… or an unknown unknown, which I cannot tell you what could they be, because - evidently - I wouldn't know. Regardless, what actually happens is what actually happens. Thus, I would encourage to test like I was saying at the start of the question, and confirm if what I'm saying is actually correct, and go from there.*